# Moving a particular column element to the top of a row in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align the section information as shown in the figure.
Here's the desktop view : [image: Requirement in Desktop View]

And here's the mobile view, The Section header "Welcome" should move to the top of the row in the mobile view as shown in the figure [image]

But in my program, it sticks with the paragraph as normally expected and comes down under the image.

NOTE: THE IMAGE SHOWN IS MY DESIRED OUTPUT which I'm not getting.
I am somewhat new to CSS and I need to solve this issue.
Here's my code

```css
.col-centered {
   text-align: left;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;    
 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-centered">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="./Assets/Welcome_image.png" alt="WelcomeImage" />
                </div>

                <section class="col-sm-7 col-centered">
                    <h2 id="textheading">Welcome</h2>
                                    <p>Provide highest quality education to students. give studnets more than what we promise them.Children of the ages between 18 months and 6 years are extremely receptive. Kids Planet Kids pre-schools' fun filled programme makes the most of this by encouraging the childrens to understand and develop socail skills, gross and fine major skills and creativity at the same time, throug songs, music and imaginative play.</p>
                    <p><mark> Read More </mark></p>

                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-centered">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="./Assets/AboutusImage.png" alt="AboutUsImage" />
                </div>
                <section class="col-sm-7 col-centered">
                    <h2 id="textheading">About Us</h2>
                    <p>Kids Planet is a leading education and test preparation comapny, head quartered in Secunderabad, has grown into a specialist, multi-location, multi-programme training provider having 118 cities across India. Kids Planet is a leading education and test preparation comapny, head quantered in secunderanbad. Has grown into a specialist, multi-location, multi-programme training provider having 118 cities across India.</p>
                    <p><mark> Read More </mark></p>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: You say you "need to solve this issue" but what is the issue? is it that the 'Welcome' heading is supposed to look like the image (but currently it does not) or that the 'Welcome' heading currently looks like the image (but it should not)?  please expand on your desired outcome

Comment: The 'Welcome' heading is supposed to look like the image (but currently it does not). I apologize for the incorrect formation of my question. I have edited it. Thanks for the reply Please help if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Now, with new information, you need to make use of the [helper classes to Show/Hide elements](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide)

I created a duplicate `h2` element to show/hide according to the width of the viewport and placed it on top of the image.  Like this:

```
  <div class="visible-xs-block col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <h2 id="textheading">Welcome</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="WelcomeImage" />
  </div>

  <section class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-0">

    <h2 id="textheading" class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block">Welcome</h2>

    ...
  </section>
```

I also removed the need for the `col-centered` and made use of the `col-xs-offset-#` as needed.

Let me know if this does not work :)

**See updated demo:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="visible-xs-block col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <h2 id="textheading">Welcome</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="WelcomeImage" />
  </div>

  <section class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-0">
    <h2 id="textheading" class="hidden-xs">Welcome</h2>
    <p>Provide highest quality education to students. give studnets more than what we promise them.Children of the ages between 18 months and 6 years are extremely receptive. Kids Planet Kids pre-schools' fun filled programme makes the most of this by encouraging
      the childrens to understand and develop socail skills, gross and fine major skills and creativity at the same time, throug songs, music and imaginative play.</p>
    <p><mark> Read More </mark></p>

  </section>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <h2 id="textheading">About Us</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="AboutUsImage" />
  </div>

  <section class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-0">
    <h2 id="textheading" class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block">About Us</h2>
    <p>Kids Planet is a leading education and test preparation comapny, head quartered in Secunderabad, has grown into a specialist, multi-location, multi-programme training provider having 118 cities across India. Kids Planet is a leading education and
      test preparation comapny, head quantered in secunderanbad. Has grown into a specialist, multi-location, multi-programme training provider having 118 cities across India.</p>
    <p><mark> Read More </mark></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

Old answer deleted after clarifications

Comment: You understood the opposite of it. Sorry for the not so correct question pattern. I need the "Heading on top of the image in Mobile view". The image  I am sharing is the required page I need to code for. For my current code, the "Heading" comes down with the paragraph below the image. I need the output just as shown in the image.

Comment: I see... I updated my answer -> the only remaining adjustment is to determine at which cutoff point do you want to switch layouts

Comment: I thought of it but didn't use cause I was unsure if my project guide would except it. He doesn't want any hacks to be used. But since you are providing me with the solution it must be the valid thing to do in such a situation/requirement(coz u have a nice profile :p)... Huge thanks

Comment: No hacks used :) - this is straight from the bootstrap library (I provided you with a link to the docs as well, in first paragraph)

Comment: Thanks, man. Appreciate such a quick reply. StackOverflow is awesome. This is my 2nd time using it.

Comment: @FaizaanKhan made a small adjustment to only add one class to hide/show (instead of many) per element